# If I get the IP adress from a user in django, how should I store it in a model?

Tags: django

I am able to find out how to get the users IP in django. But, I do not know how to store it in a model. I was planning on just putting it in a TextField.

Comment: here the [genericipaddressfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#genericipaddressfield) and on the page you can look for other field types.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dedicated [field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot